# Upgrade user control

Tags: upgrade, user-controls

We have a SharePoint 2010 project which we are trying to uprgade to SharePoint 2013.I am not familiar with sharepoint development. How can I upgrade user controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally SP 2010 project should work in 2013. You can try deploying WSP and review if it works. Else you can follow one of the option below

You can do this in three ways

**One**

1. Creating a new SharePoint 2013 project using Visual Studio 2013. Then insert new item -> User Control (choose the same name)
2. Now copy files from Old project and replace files in new project
3. Try building project - Fix error and deploy and test

**Two**

2013 comes with new development models. Review what the current user control does and try to create a new App which does the same.

**Three**

Open 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2013, this will automatically upgrade the project. Now build and fix errors and deploy & test

Comment: Two is hilarious! like it was an easy task :D